# c# Sending email though smtp mail format error happens

Tags: c#, email, smtp, visual-c#-express-2010

Hello I am using visual c# 2010 and I am trying to send an email with gmail but I get an exception when I try to send the email at:

```
MailMessage mail = new MailMessage(From.Text, To.Text, Subject.Text , richTextBox2.Text);
```

`From.Text`, `To.Text`, `Subject.Text`, `richTextBox2.Text` are all text boxes with the information inside.

Here is the whole mail segment I am using:

```
SmtpClient client = new SmtpClient(smtp.Text);
            client.Port = 587;
            client.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential(Username.Text, Password.Text);
            client.EnableSsl = true;
            client.Send(mail);
            MessageBox.Show("mail sent");
```

**The exception is**: FormatException was Unhanded

**The exception description is** :The specified string is not in the form required for an e-mail address

And I have tried just filling the information out like so :

```
MailMessage mail = new MailMessage("you@gmail.com", "me@gmail.com", "hello" , body.Text);
                                   //example       //example
```

But I still get an exception. What am I doing wrong ?

Here are the values :

```
 To.Text = "gerardcrafting@gmail.com";
        smtp.Text = "smtp.gmail.com";
        Password.Text = "Password";
        Username.Text = "staff.gerardcrafting.gmail.com"; 
        Subject.Text = textBox1.Text + "Banned" + richTextBox4.Text;
```

Comment: Have you put break points in your code to see exactly which line is causing the exception?

Comment: @KarlAnderson sorry yes i did but i did not put that in the question

Comment: smtp.Text does this have value?

Comment: @KarlAnderson yes 'MailMessage mail = new MailMessage(From.Text, To.Text, Subject.Text , body.Text);' is causing it

Comment: Are the values of `From.Text` and `To.Text` in email@host.com format?
What is the value of smtp.Text? It should be `"smtp.gmail.com"`.
Is your Username.Text value just the email? Instead of email@host.com?
I was able to send an email fine with my gmail.

Comment: So what are the values of each piece? `From.Text`, `To.Text`, `Subject.Text` and `body.Text`?

Comment: @EhsanUllah yes it is a text box with "smtp.gmail.com" inside of it

Comment: @making3 yes they have the user name and password inside of it i checked the formatting on gmail

Comment: @KarlAnderson well i will obisly mute my passwords but they are  From.Text  = taff.gerardcrafting.gmail.com                      To.Text = gerardcrafting@gmail.com  Subject.Text = edited by user and body is edited by user i will just show my code

Comment: @making3 i have update the code to show the values but it is saying that it is the way i formatted the  line 'MailMessage mail = new MailMessage(From.Text, To.Text, Subject.Text , body.Text);'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per the MSDN documentation for [MailMessage Constructor (String, String, String, String)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5k0ddab0.aspx), when a `FormatException` happens with this constructor the reason is:

`from or to is malformed.`

You stated that your `From.Text` is `taff.gerardcrafting.gmail.com`, that is not a valid email address, because it is missing the `@` symbol.

Comment: thank you so much i overlooked a small thing and it stopped my whole application than you so much

Comment: No problem, if you feel this answer helped you then please upvote and/or accept the answer.

Comment: 1 more thing if you know how to help i am getting a exseption saying "The SMTP server requires a secure connection or the client was not authenticated. The server response was: 5.5.1 Authentication Required. Learn more at" buti have  client.EnableSsl set to true

Comment: @Gerard2202 - My guess is since you have set SSL to true, that the username/password you are sending to GMail is incorrect and is not being authenticated correctly. If you have verified that the values are correct, then I would recommend asking another question specific to the GMail authentication issue.

Answer (score 1):

Change the input of `Username.Text` to simply `"gerardcrafting"`.